# Find row with certain value, then select next X rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something that should be relatively simpel, I guess, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I want to find a certain id in a table, and then select the next X rows that meet a certain criteria.

Example table:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| id | type | value | sorting |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1   | 'x'  | 'foo' | 1       |
|2   | 'y'  | 'bar' | 5       |
|3   | 'z'  | 'foo2'| 9       |
|4   | 'z'  | 'bar2'| 29      |
|5   | 'x'  | 'foo3'| 3       |
|6   | 'z'  | 'bar3'| 11      |
|7   | 'z'  | 'foo4'| 4       |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want is to select the next X rows where `type = 'z'` starting from row with `id = 3`, sorted by `sorting`.

So for this table, I would want to get rows with id `3, 6, 4`, in that order. Note that row with id `7` matches the type, but it's `sorting` value is lower than row with id `3`.

Can this be done in one query?

---

My ideas: for the example table, something as such would do:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'z' AND sorting > 9 ORDER BY sorting LIMIT 3, X`

But obviously, I can't know the values 9 and the offset yet, so I'd need a way to:

1. Find the sorting value for id `3`.
2. Find the offset for id `3`.
3. Apply those to the query.

---

Edit: Where I'm at now:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM table
WHERE type = 'z' AND sorting > (SELECT sorting FROM table WHERE id = 3)
ORDER BY sorting 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

So the last step is to get the offset of `3` and pass that as the first parameter to LIMIT.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Added to the question!

Comment: `LIMIT 3, X` do yuo need 2? 3? infinite? number of records returned?  *2. Find the offset for id 3.* - why do you need to find offset?

Comment: Let's say I need 10 additional records returned.

Comment: How do you find the offset? That is not clear at all. Why isn't "4" returned in your sample result set. It is also `z` and, according to the sort, is next in line after id `6`

Comment: Agree with @JNevill  - not clear. It sounds like you need multiple subqueries for each 'rule' you're stating. But it's not clear what happens in what order. Good luck.

Comment: You're right, `4` should be returned too. Updated. Also added next step to question.

Comment: you started from limit 2, then 10 now 25, it seem you don't need limit at all :-)) same as offset by the way :-)

Comment: I do need LIMIT, but I also need OFFSET. `LIMIT 5, 10` == `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5`. It's the offset that's changing, not the limit.

Comment: Check your comment above: *Let's say I need 10 additional records returned* so are you still sure *It's the offset that's changing, not the limit* ? :-) because checking your OP last edition  **LIMIT 0, 25** isn't it?

Comment: You're right :-) it is changing, but in the production version of this problem, which is more complex, I do need some sort of limit, later to be determined.

Comment: I very doubt on that. But have you ever check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is still not clear. But here is my attempt:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d389/1

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM foobar t1
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM foobar 
      WHERE id=3
) t2 
ON t1.id >= t2.id
   AND t1.type = t2.type
   AND t1.sorting >= t2.sorting
ORDER BY sorting
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Trying to access the fiddle but it won't load :-(

Comment: Just retry, sometimes site is kind of overloaded but you should finally get it. And the query itself pretty easy to test on your side.

Comment: It works! Great. Can you elaborate on the meaning of `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: Those are just aliases to manipulate with tables. Especially in your case when we join table to itself but we need to know where is left table and where is right table.

Comment: Ah I see. Perfect. Thanks a lot!